# How to tell scanf to index the characters if you get to max size OR an "enter" was clicked?

Tags: c

I want to index a word, but I want the size of the array to change according to the word entered if its smaller that the size limit..this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
int main(void)

{
    int index;
    char wordToPrint[SIZE];
    printf("please enter a random word:\n");
    for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &wordToPrint[index]);
    }
    for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        printf("%c", wordToPrint[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What should I add to define that?

tnx

Comment: @squiguy thank you, although I didnt get to fgets and in the exercise scanf is required..if you know a solution using scanf i'ld be great :)

Comment: If you must use `scanf()`, remember that `scanf()` returns a value and it may put something in `wordToPrintf[index]` (since that's what you're asking it to do).  You can use those pieces of information to determine whether enter was pressed.

Comment: If you got what he told, please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: if you want to change the size of the array, you need a dynamic array, prefereably some std container

Comment: ok, you are using a static array. If you meant the memory size of the array, dynamic array using malloc/calloc will be best. Or, Do you mean length of the string/word to vary? And what do you mean by index the characters?

Comment: @askmish hi, what i mean to do is, if the size i limited is 10 char max, so if the user will enter 5, i want to change the size to 6, so there is no extra 4..

Comment: So you want to change the memory size of the array from 10 bytes to 6 bytes or just the string size from 10 to 6,keeping the memory size constant?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
int main(void)
{
    int index;

    // declare a pointer variable to point to allocated space
    char *wordToPrint;

    printf("enter the size of string MAX is 10");
    scanf("%d",&index);
    if(index > 10){ 
       printf("out of allowd limit");
    } else {

        // call malloc to allocate that appropriate number of bytes for the array
        wordToPrint= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*index);      // allocate

        // use [] notation to access array buckets
        for(i=0; i < index; i++) 
        {
           scanf("%c",&wordToPrint[i]);
        }
        for (i= 0; i< index; i++)
        {
           printf("%c", wordToPrint[i]);
        }
        free(wordToPrint);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Dynamic memory allocation can only be done in c through malloc or calloc function you can ask the use to enter max size and check if that exceed  the allowed limit else you get the array with the size of user input value like if user enter 5 you get array of size 5 char